# error while inserting data into database table through XPC UI

Tags: tooltwist

2012-10-31 11:41:09,895 DEBUG UpdatePluggin - insert into get_people (person_name) values (?)
2012-10-31 11:41:09,913 DEBUG UpdatePluggin - Parameter0(OTHER)=Adam
com.dinaa.xpc.XpcException: Could not find configuration file 'conf/skipEntitiesForAudit.conf'
    at tooltwist.misc.AuditTransactionTracking.(AuditTransactionTracking.java:55)
    at tooltwist.misc.AuditTransactionTracking.getTransactionObject(AuditTransactionTracking.java:87)
    at com.dinaa.sql.UpdatePluggin.runMethod(UpdatePluggin.java:1014)
    at com.dinaa.xpc.backend.XpcInternal.opEntity(XpcInternal.java:176)
    at com.dinaa.xpc.backend.XpcInternal.opEntityList(XpcInternal.java:288)
    at com.dinaa.xpc.backend.XpcInternal.op(XpcInternal.java:82)
    at com.dinaa.xpc.Xpc.op(Xpc.java:660)
    at tooltwist.workbench.XpcTestServlet.doPost(XpcTestServlet.java:103)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 1):

To stop this error being displayed go into the ToolTwist Workbench, create a file named **config/skipEntitiesForAudit.conf** in project ***ttWbd***, and insert this line:

> <config/>

Alternately, you can create .../devel/ttWbd/conf/skipEntitiesForAudit.conf from the command line.